# Unequally sized and undistinguishable groups

Tags: probability, combinatorics

My question is about using the multinomial coefficient in the case of unequally sized and undistinguishable groups.

Let's say we are dividing 13 people into 5 groups of size 2, 2, 3, 3 and 3. If the groups are not distinguishable, (ex: the groups are two identical cars that sit 2 people, and three identical cars that sit 3 people), then the number of possibilities are

$$\frac{\binom{13}{2,2,3,3,3}}{2!\times 3!} = \frac{13!}{2! \times 2! \times 3! \times 3! \times 3! \times 2! \times 3!}$$

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- What you propose as a solution is not an integer.
- Your calculation of $13!$ is way off:

$$
13!=6227020800\ne20\;.
$$

- Other than that, your approach is correct; the count is

$$
\frac{13!}{2!^33!^4}=600600\;.
$$

Comment: sorry it is a typo

Comment: @trueblueanil: I did, thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use such option:

$$
\text{ways=}\frac{\binom{13}{2}\binom{11}{2}\binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{3}}{{2!}\cdot{3!}}=600600.
$$